# Send POST parameters with gmail inbox - GO TO ACTIONS?

Tags: google-schemas

Is it possible to send `POST` parameters with `GMAIL GO-TO ACTIONS` with specified url?
If yes, how to send and capture those parameters on landing page?

I was working with `"Track pakage"` button with `GMAIL-INBOX ACTIONS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the parameters you need to the endpoint url, but it is not possible to add a custom request body.

Comment: I want to send POST request to track url. I don't want my request parameteres visible in url.